# Python code inconsistency

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following code, this is a plugin for Sublime Editor:

```
old_viewport_position = self.view.viewport_position()
x = old_viewport_position[0]
y = old_viewport_position[1]
// smth happens
self.view.set_viewport_position((x,y))
// or self.view.set_viewport_position(old_viewport_position) 
print(old_viewport_position) //(0.0, 2759.0)
print(x) //0.0
print(y) //2759.0
```

And the result is not which must be using this `x`, `y`.

But if I make a hardcode of this value, for example:

```
self.view.set_viewport_position((0.0, 1339))
```

Then the result is what is expected.
In the first case it seems like there is no the line `set_viewport_position` at all.
Still `print` shows that the values are valid. My question is what can it be with this tuple or function which takes this tuple that in the same code, values from runtime don't work, but values from hardcode works.

Comment: What does `print(old_viewport_position)` print exactly?

Comment: What is unexpected about the the result with (x,y)?

Comment: Make sense to me that unless you change the values of `x` and/or `y`, the effect of `self.view.set_viewport_position((x,y))` _will_ be like there was no line `set_viewport_position` because nothing changed it -- you're just setting it to what it already is.

Comment: @ placeybordeaux My view always goes to the top (0.0, 0.0). And By my code I am trying to preserve the position of the viewport. @ martineau  It is impossible because from my answer to placeybordeaux u can see that smth changes it. And also how I wrote hardcode values make the position changing effect, what do not do runtime values.

Comment: The error is probably in the "smth happens". As it is we can't help you with this question, voting to close.